# Need javascript path

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to reference a variable (in this case, zipCode) but I'm having trouble defining the javascript path. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var uoPurchase = {
                product:"Ticket;110144206100;1;214.99;Adult",
                purchasePriceBeforeTax: "214.99",
                orderID: "150819UO62768693",
                zipCode: "32109",
                creditCardType: "Visa",
                deliveryType: "87",
                quantity: "1",
                adults: "1",
                children: "0",
                allAges: "0",
                dates: "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"
            };
    </script>
```

Comment: Or `uoPurchase['zipCode']`.

Comment: Here is an example in jsfiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/cguen7ka/

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Unfortunately I've tried both uoPurchase.zipCode and uoPurchase['zipCode'] without any luck. Originally, the path was set to window.uoPurchase.zipCode - any other ideas?